# HtmAgilityPack not returning all nodes

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape data from here http://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php

Here is my code

```
        var parser = new HtmlDocument();
        parser.LoadHtml(html);

        var datas = parser.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr/@data-eventid");
```

where `html` is loaded from the link above.

Problem is, the nodes retrieved are not consistent. Under debugger, it only returns 14 nodes and others are somehow sort of error (came out as `?`). But under QuickWatch window, it returns all nodes. I am not quite sure why is this happening.

Even if I use chrome console, it retrieves all nodes, so the markup is right. `$x("//tr/@data-eventid")` in chrome console.

[image: Not okay]
[image: Okay]

Comment: Not sure what is your exact problem... Debugger have a lot of "random" restrictions to keep it somewhat fast (like no automatic expansion of enumrations...) and different windows (immediate, watch, local, hover-over,...) likely have different limits too... If you are not happy with particular debugging window try other ones (i.e. Watch seem to be working for you in this case) or write your own viewer...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just realized this is such a silly question. ? means that the item hasn't been iterated yet. I thought there were some errors with the the `HtmlAgilityPack`. If you could answer it below I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is debugger specific behavior, most likely data itself is fine.

Debugger have a lot of "random" restrictions to keep it somewhat fast (like no automatic expansion of enumerations...) and different windows (immediate, watch, local, hover-over,...) likely have different limits too.

If you are not happy with particular debugging window try other ones (i.e. Watch seem to be working for you in this case) or write your own [visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx).